# Can't get upper Table border

Tags: tables, border

I need your help in allowing an upper border for a table.
many posts have suggested that this should be written:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
```

I have done so but did not get an upper boundary, in my code I have done:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|}
```

please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider dropping the use of vertical rules, as suggested in [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).

Comment: If you aren't using booktabs, use \hline instead of \toprule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for

```
\begin{tabular}[.]{..}
  \hline
```

However, I'd suggest

```
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{tabular}[.]{..}
  \toprule
```

and use all of the associated `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` provided by [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).